# Rails Ajax/Controller not properly updating my partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-6

i'm working through a tutorial to get a rails partial to display stock information using ajax.  Everything is working properly and in the console I can see that the div has been updated properly, but it isn't being displayed.  Here's the relevant code.

CONTROLLER

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController 
   def search
      if params[:stock].present?
         @stock = Stock.new_from_lookup(params[:stock])
         if @stock 
            puts "should be working"
            respond_to do |format|
            format.js { render partial: 'users/result' }            
            end

         else
            puts "incorrect symbol"
            flash[:danger] = "You have entered an incorrect symbol."
            redirect_to my_portfolio_path
         end

      else
         puts "nothing"
         flash[:danger] = "You need to type something, what did you expect to happen?"
         redirect_to my_portfolio_path
      end
   end
end
```

AJAX JS ERB

```
$('#results").html("<%=j (render 'users/result.html')%>")
```

The result of the partial is

```
<%if @stock%>
    <div class = "well results-block">
        <strong>Symbol:</strong><%= @stock.ticker%>
        <strong>Name:</strong><%= @stock.name%>
        <strong>Last Price:</strong><%= @stock.last_price%>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

Let me know if there's more info you need.  I'm using Rails 6.

Comment: what is the content of 'users/result.html' ?

Comment: I saved it in the edit for ya!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#partial-layouts . You should try dropping 'partial' or add 'locals' or 'object' to render method.

> all of the following render calls would all render the edit.html.erb template in the views/books directory:

```rb
render :edit
render action: :edit
render "edit"
render action: "edit"
render "books/edit"
render template: "books/edit"
```

> You can pass an object in to this local variable via the :object option:

```rb
<%= render partial: "customer", object: @new_customer %>
```

In your case,

```rb
format.js { render 'users/result' }
```

Comment: Where should i put that second to last line?

Comment: Also, when I go in and preview it, I can see this: $('#results").html("    <div class = \"well results-block\">\n        <strong>Symbol:<\/strong>GOOG\n        <strong>Name:<\/strong>Alphabet, Inc.\n        <strong>Last Price:<\/strong>1340.74\n    <\/div>\n")  Making me know it IS getting the info, just not actually refreshing the partial

Comment: Open up the web inspector. In the console tab run the result code, see it does work or not.

Comment: It is showing the html code for the partial in the results tab with the correct info in it...it just isn't actually pushing that partial to the screen.

Comment: if you are sure you got the html code for the partial, make sure the page (that is calling search action) has a single html tag with `id=results` (most commonly `div`)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
$('#results").html("<%=j (render 'users/result.html')%>")
```

Did you try to use

```
document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = '<%= j render 'users/result.html' %>'
```

This works fine for me.